# Jquery calling function after ajax load fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

We have an external javascript file that gets called as part of a catalog results page, AJAX is involved on this document - https://www.columnradiators4u.co.uk/uk/classic-white-column-radiators.html

I have a jquery function for altering colour of a span when it detects certain text - please see my code below.

```
function ReInitStockColor(){
 $(function() {
  $("span:contains(In Stock)").css("font-weight", "bold").css("color", "#00BF00");
  $("span:contains(Due)").css("color", "#FF0000");
  $("span:contains(Made)").css("font-weight", "bold").css("color", "#00BF00");
 });
}
```

This code is being called earlier on in our file, however it is not executing. If I take my code in to chrome/Firefox console and run it, it executes successfully.

Is anybody able to assist in this matter?

EDIT: Full JS file here: https://jsfiddle.net/8z8oq2sm/
EDIT 08/01: Anybody able to offer any further help? I've tried the suggestions below to no avail.

Comment: why place an "document.ready" function inside a named function?

Comment: Hi Kaddath,
This was pointed out to me by Nikanor as well - I have omitted that part of the code. Thank you. 
Unfortunately the code still does not fire, keen to find out why!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() { ... });
```

is just jQuery short-hand for

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

$(function() { ... }); suggests that code will be executed only on document ready. And you have it inside function ReInitStockColor. Can you remove that  $(function() { ... }) thing and see if this ReInitStockColor function is being called?

Comment: Hi Nikanor,
I've got a call to the ReInitStockColor() higher up in the document, after removing the second document ready the script still does not fire - any ideas?

Comment: Please provide full code, show the way you call this function.

Comment: Hi Nikanor, I'm unsure that I can paste the code, there's over 7,000 lines in total! I'll try to do what I can below - EDIT: Just one of the calls is over 2,300 characters. is JSfiddle appropriate?

https://jsfiddle.net/63Lf4usg/

Answer (score 0):

You should call this `ReInitStockColor()` function with in the AJAX **success** or **done** function

Answer (score 0):

you need this?

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Abolfazl,
How would this be used?

Comment: for effective all ajax requests failure; In general, at the beginning of your code